# LayeredLayout container, as background, changes to white colour when clicked in Codenameone

Tags: java, android, codenameone

Please can you help. I have a very simple example below of a page which i want to have a 2 coloured background, with a diagonal split, which i have achieved. As this is on a LayeredLayout then i will overlay my page content onto it.

[image: Screenshot]

All is fine in the simulator, but when i put the app on my android device, then when i press on any part of the screen, the top left triangle change to white, and then changes back when i un-press. The bottom right triangle remains as is correctly.

As this is a background to the main page then i clearly don't want this colour change to happen. 
Many thanks

A sample project class is here:

```
    package com.test;


import com.codename1.ui.Button;
import com.codename1.ui.Component;
import com.codename1.ui.Container;
import com.codename1.ui.Form;
import com.codename1.ui.Graphics;
import com.codename1.ui.geom.Dimension;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BorderLayout;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BoxLayout;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.LayeredLayout;

public class AndroidKeyboard {
    private Form currentForm = new Form("", new BorderLayout());

    public void buildPage() {
        Container background = getBackground();
        currentForm.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, background);
        Button button = new Button("Click me");
        currentForm.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, button);
        currentForm.show();
    }

    int topColour = 0x4371A4;
    int bottomColour = 0x70AEEA;

    private Container getBackground() {

        Container layeredContainer = new Container(new LayeredLayout());
        layeredContainer.setName("BackgroundContainer");

        currentForm.getToolbar().getAllStyles().setBgColor(topColour);
        currentForm.getToolbar().getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(255);
        //
        layeredContainer.getAllStyles().setBgColor(topColour);
        layeredContainer.getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(255);

        TopTriangleComponent t = new TopTriangleComponent();
        t.setTopColour(topColour);
        layeredContainer.add(t);

        BottomTriangleComponent b = new BottomTriangleComponent();
        b.setBottomColour(bottomColour);
        layeredContainer.add(b);
        return layeredContainer;
    }
}

class TopTriangleComponent extends Component {

    private int topColour;

    protected void setTopColour(int colour) {
        topColour = colour;
    }

    @Override
    protected Dimension calcPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(250, 250);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(topColour);
        int[] int_x = new int[] { 0, getWidth(), 0 };
        int[] int_y = new int[] { 0, 0, getHeight() };

        g.fillPolygon(int_x, int_y, 3);
    }
}

class BottomTriangleComponent extends Component {

    private int bottomColour;

    protected void setBottomColour(int colour) {
        bottomColour = colour;
    }

    @Override
    protected Dimension calcPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(250, 250);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(bottomColour);
        int[] int_x = new int[] { getWidth(), getWidth(), 0 };
        int[] int_y = new int[] { 0, getHeight(), getHeight() };

        g.fillPolygon(int_x, int_y, 3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating two opaque containers but only paint a portion of them. Then when lay them one on top of the other and rely on the fact that you only drew some of the container. That works for some forms of paint (bottom to top) but when you click an an area we only paint the changes. At that point we check the opacity to prevent the cost of painting "everything" all over again.

Specifically this line is the problem:

```
currentForm.getToolbar().getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(255);
```

It should be `0` to indicate the desired transparency. But I would avoid that layered approach altogether as it's just really expensive if you draw anyway. Might as well draw everything. In that case you don't need a container just a `Painter` and you can apply it to the background of any arbitrary component using styles: `setBgPainter(Painter)`.

Notice that `setBgTransparency(255)` would work correctly at that point and would be the right option since you won't have additional items behind you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Shai Almog. I have now reworked the container to use the Painter class and it resolves the problem. New code below:

```
public class AndroidKeyboard {
private Form currentForm = new Form("", new BorderLayout());

public void buildPage() {
    Container background = getBackground();
    currentForm.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, background);
    Button button = new Button("Click me");
    currentForm.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, button);
    currentForm.show();
}

int topColour = 0x4822A4;
int bottomColour = 0x20AEEA;

private Container getBackground() {
    Container cmp = new Container();
    Painter p = new Painter() {
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g, Rectangle rect) {
            boolean antiAliased = g.isAntiAliased();
            g.setAntiAliased(true);

            g.setColor(topColour);

            int[] int_x = new int[] { 0, currentForm.getWidth(), 0 };
            int[] int_y = new int[] { 0, 0, currentForm.getHeight() };

            g.fillPolygon(int_x, int_y, 3);

            g.setColor(bottomColour);
            int[] int_x2 = new int[] { currentForm.getWidth(), currentForm.getWidth(), 0 };
            int[] int_y2 = new int[] { 0, currentForm.getHeight(), currentForm.getHeight() };

            g.fillPolygon(int_x2, int_y2, 3);
            g.setAntiAliased(antiAliased);
        }
    };
    cmp.getAllStyles().setBgPainter(p);
    return cmp;
}
```